# In a weighted undirected graph, how do I find a fixed length path between two nodes?

Tags: math, graph, path, nodes, shortest-path

I would like an algorithm or pointers to further research on how to find a fixed length path between two nodes in a weighted undirected graph.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a simple path from a given node to a given node with a given length is NP-complete: The [Hamiltonian cycle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is a problem of this class and it is NP-complete.

If the edges are weighted, then the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is a special case of this problem, so we're still NP-complete

In both cases, you can enumerate the paths, pruning paths that are not simple or paths that are too long in `theta(b^len)` expected time where `b` is the branching factor (an average outdegree).

---

Finding a path which allows repeated edges (sometimes called a walk) can be done in [length] matrix multiplications, totalling `O(v^3 * len)` time complexity [or better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Let `A` represent the adjacency matrix of the graph. Then `A^len` holds the number of paths of length len between each pair of vertices. You can use `1+1 = 1` during the multiplication (boolean addition - not sure how it plays with the advanced matrix multiplication algorithms), then you only get the existence of such a path but you avoid integer overflow at the same time.

Prepare `A^1..A^len` (`O(n^3 len)`). Then, for each distance `d` in `1..len`, find a vertex `v[d]` that is a child of `v[d-1]` and that has a `len-d`-long path to the target (`O(n len)`).

If you only need to know if such a path exists, then you don't need `A..A^len`, only `A^len`. You can compute it in `O(n^3 log(len))` time by the [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm, or even `O(n^2.37 log(len))` when coupled with the [Coppersmith-Winograd matrix multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm).

---

alternatively, you can just search the `[node x distance]` state space and have it done in `O(n*b*len)`.